# PHP number of results from Oracle query

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I am doing a select in my Oracle database and need to take different actions for the result being false (contains no results) or being true (contains one or more results).

However testing the result in the following way gives me a problem. In the cases where I actually have results from my query the `if(!` naturally validates to false and moves on to the `else` statement - perfect!

But when doing this test the internal pointer moves in the result and thereby the first result is lost when performing the `while` statement later.

```
if (!($row = oci_fetch_array($get_doc_paths, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))){
    do something
}

else {
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($get_doc_paths, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
        do something with $row
    }           
}
```

How do I test if there are results without moving the internal pointer?

In MySQL I would have used the mysqli_num_rows or simply just reset the pointer. I can't find a way to do this with Oracle.

Comment: How about `oci_num_rows` http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php ?

Comment: @Rahman The page states that "This function does not return number of rows selected!"

Comment: With MySQL experience it might sound like the one to use - unfortunately it doesn't do what it sounds like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$status = false;

while($row = oci_fetch_array(...)) {
    $status = true;
    // Do something with row
}

if(!$status) {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Interesting and simple approach!

Comment: Seems like that Oracle should have better solution, but this solution does the trick!